# Some RSACryptoServiceProvider methods not available in .net 4.5.2

Tags: c#, .net, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I'm facing an issue trying to use some RSACryptoServiceProvider methods, more specific the VerifyData().

I'm working on a project which compiles in both net452 and netstandard2.0.

When I add the nugget and try to use it's methods, I see the following message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Unlq.png)

Does anyone knows why is this happening? Because regarding to the official microsoft documentation this library is compatible with net452.

Thank you so much!

I did a research in order to find different rsa tools

Comment: Net 4.52 does not handle all encryption modes.  When Net 4.5.2 did not handle an encryption mode many people resorted to OpenSSL to handle the encryption.

Comment: I have seen some examples of OpenSSL encryption with .Net framework but at the very end they use the System.Security.Cryptography to validate the signature.

Comment: The validate signature is different from the encryption mode.  
Signing is the same type of signing as signing  pdf document.  The signature just makes sure somebody didn't change the contents of the PEM ( other key file).  It is not the encryption mode (and key) that is used to make an http  connection.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: My bad about uploading an image. Sorry, didn't know that but makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Standard 2.0 is aligned with .NET Framework 4.7.2, not .NET Framework 4.5.2.  The particular method you're looking at was added in .NET Framework 4.6.

FWIW, .NET Framework 4.5.2 (and 4.6, and 4.6.1) went [out of support in 2022](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/) so you should hopefully be able to move your netfx minimum to 4.6.2 with little resistance.